# Are you using custom rails environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ootb rails has the 3 environments

- development
- test
- production

How do you handle your other environments for example staging ?

When I think about what I want from a staging environment I want most of the production settings, but typically server names and other specific values are different from production.

Do you create 1:N environment/*.rb for each custom environment you have? Or do you treat the environments more as like a *profile* and then use something like application.yml or secrets.yml for running the application with different server configurations?

What has worked well for you in the past and what has not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if your "staging" environment is a different thing or is actually a variation on the "production" environment as is usually the case.

Normally you just deploy in full production mode, using the `production.rb` file and everything, to a non-production server. This distinction is irrelevant to rails, and matters only to your deployment script. For example [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) would be concerned about this.

The only time you need another environment is if you need a different group of settings for Rails.

Comment: What do you do in your deployment script? Do you write the settings out to a file that gets loaded? Modify production.rb during deploy?

Comment: Usually nothing has to change in `production.rb` because you're not tweaking how the application runs, only the database configuration and such. Those are typically handled by `config/deploy/staging.rb` for example. Adding Capistrano is not that hard and usually saves a ton of time. Life without deployment automation is really grim.

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate any way described above.

In some cases I am using 1:N way because it easy when you have fixed count of deployment environments (for example when I am deploying own pet-project to remote server).

But in other cases I am using default set of environments (for example when I am deploying project to different customers).

Just choose any way appropriate for you and your project.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, when I run the app in an staging environment I want it to have exactly the same settings as in production, because it's when I check if everything is alright before releasing the new code. So I create a `environments/staging.rb` that actually is a symbolic link to `environments/production.rb`. To deploy, I use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/), which lets you define the server settings for every environment you want to. I really encourage you to take a look at it if you don't know it, as it makes deploying as easy as running a simple command, and it takes care of uploading the new code, precompiling the assets, restarting the server, etc.

Comment: We are sadly not using capistrano......yet I'm still working on upgrading this thing from rails 2 to 3 :(  But the sort of settings I'm talking about are this database connection, this email server, this network printer etc. How does capistrano work its magic is it writing the settings out to a file? modifying the production.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

I use `require_relative` to create a staging environment that is identical to production, and then override the parts that are different. Typically the only difference is hostnames.

Here's what my `environments/staging.rb` looks like:

```
# Staging configuration is identical to production, with some overrides
# for hostname, etc.

require_relative "./production"

Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    :host => "staging.example.com",
    :protocol => "https"
  }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "https://staging.example.com"
end
```